# How to show space on line break

Tags: html, css

In my `<p>` tag I have some text, and it's broken on many lines.

```
<p>
some really long text broken in many places...
</p>
```

Normal behavior is not to show space character on line break, but in my application I need to show it, is it possible in any way ?

**EDIT:**

If You run [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Nmr/):

```
<p style="width:100px;">
    <span style="background-color: #008000">
        some long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </span>
</p>
```

You can see, that space ("&#32") between words, appears like any other character, but there is no space on the end of each line.

Comment: what do you mean by "show space characters" ?

Comment: you can use `<pre>` or `<br />` tag.

Comment: Alternatively, have a look at the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) property.

Comment: Its not about breaking a line, take a look at edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer can be found in the css `white-space` property. This should be your HTML:

```
<p style="width:100px;">
  <span style="background:#008000;">some long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
</p>
```

And your CSS should be:

```
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

One problem with `white-space:pre-wrap;` though, is that it also includes all tabs you may use in your HTML formatting. So you can't indent the text inside the `<span>` tags.

Take a look at this fiddle I made: [jsfiddle.net/jWbgW/](http://jsfiddle.net/jWbgW/)

Of course, you should really put all your style definitions in the css, but that's a given.

Comment: That's it! Thx a lot - idk why but when I was experimenting with white-space I just skipped "pre-wrap".

Answer (score 1):

The space character is not actually displayed at the end of a line. If you set `white-space: pre` on the `span` element, then its content will be displayed as is, preserving the division into lines as well as multiple or end-of-line spaces. To have just some individual space(s) at ends of lines displayed (in the sense that they occupy space and get background color), you can use no-break spaces, representable as `&nsbsp;`.

But if you would like to have text wrapped as usual, then I’m afraid there is no simple way to make browsers append such a “visible space” at the ends of lines.

Answer (score 0):

To add a line break in HTML between different paragraph sections you can wrap each section in `<P></P>` tags, use a `<BR />`, or use CSS padding-bottom attribute.  When you use each of these really depends on the situation.

Here's a good article that offers some good explanation: http://www.newbiewebsitedesign.com/html-line-break-tag-cod

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br />` for new line or margin/padding in CSS.

```
<p>
some really long text broken in many places...
<br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p { white-space:nowrap;}

<p>This text will be not broken on many lines...</p>
```

Check this out too: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/